# Variable not being passed properly during image upload

Tags: php, html, forms

I'm trying to have an **upload button** next to each recipes on my page, so I need to **pass the recipe ID value** during the image upload so that the image path gets saved next to each recipes in my database. But for some reasons, I keep on getting the same error:

```
 Notice: Undefined index: recipe_id in C:\xampp\htdocs\upload.php on line 4
```

Line 4 is : `$recipe_id = $_POST['recipe_id'];`

Here is the HTML form:

```
<div class="upload_icon">
  <form id="<?php echo $recipe_id ?>" action="upload.php" method="POST"   
  enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="image"  value="<?php echo $recipe_id ?>"/></input>
    <button type="submit" name="submit" value="add">Add image!</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

PHP part (upload.php) :

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST");
  {

   $recipe_id = $_POST['recipe_id'];
   $name = $_FILES ['image'] ['name'];
   $tmp_name = $_FILES ['image'] ['tmp_name'];   

   $location = "uploads/$name";
   move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $location);

   $update = query("UPDATE menu SET recipe_pic = '".$location."' WHERE recipe_id =   
  '$recipe_id' " );
  }   

?>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're trying to pass the variable in the file input.  Create a different (hidden) input with the name and value that you want to use in the form submit PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't passing a variable with the name `recipe_id` to your PHP script - there's no input with that name in your form. Try this:

```
<form id="<?php echo $recipe_id ?>" action="upload.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="image" />
<input name="recipe_id" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $recipe_id ?>">
<button type="submit" name="submit" value="add">Add image!</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

There's no mention of `recipe_id` in your rendered HTML. Try this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="recipe_id" value="<?php echo $recipe_id ?>">
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<input type="hidden" name="recipe_id" value="<?php echo $recipe_id; ?>">
```